# Fill the tree from center to outside

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I am trying my hands on SVG and i made this
[link](http://harshbalot.freeiz.com/new/preloader2/new4.html). Now I want to know how to fill the tree in the background from center to outwards. It currently just fades in.
Here is the animation code :

```
            .st0 {
                fill:#22a8d5;
                fill-opacity: 0;
                animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-iteration: 1;
                animation-name: fillup;
                animation-duration: 4s;
                animation-delay: 4s;

            }
            @-webkit-keyframes fillup {
                from { fill-opacity: 0; }
                to { fill-opacity: 1; }
            }
```

I have tried but i just cant get it to work, It either slides in or fades in.

Comment: create a clip path using a rect, clip the cross, grow the rect over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible approaches:

1. Turn the tree into a `<clipPath>`, then use it to clip a circle whose radius you animate over time.
2. Use a `<radialGradient>` for the `fill` of the tree. Then animate the gradient's radius over time.

The first approach you can achieve using pure CSS, as long as you use `transform` to grow the circle. Animating the circle's `r` attribute will currently only work in Chrome.

The second approach can only be achieved with pure CSS on Chrome. You would need to either use an SVG `<animate>` element, or Javascript to do the animation, if you want cross-browser support.

Comment: Thank you. I took the 2nd Approach

Comment: Can you tel me how do i start the animation after the cross is done?

Comment: It depends on what method you are using to do the animation.